# Why? From CMS/pkcs#7 to Cades

Tags: digital-signature

Is that I know that the lack of some information in the `CMs/pkcs#7` signature  to prove the validity of signatures after a long period has resorted to `CADES` formats, is there other Reasons why users are migrate from the `CMs/pkcs#7` fomats to `Cades`.

what are the advantages and disadvantages of each format.
thank you in advance

Comment: CAdES essentially is a specially profiled CMS. Thus, you don't migrate away from CMS but merely follow some stricter or more concrete rules.

Comment: "some stricter or more concrete rules". like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CAdES essentially is a specially profiled CMS ("C" in CAdES after all represents "CMS"). Thus, you don't migrate away from CMS but merely follow some stricter or more concrete rules.

CMS signatures ([RFC 5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652)) may be extremely primitive, they actually need not even contain any signed attributes at all, and if they do, the only ones enforced are type and hash of the signed data.

Such minimalist signature containers are not useful for general use. There is too much opportunity for forgery (there is no assured, signed information on the signer) and too little information for proper validation.

Thus, many extra specifications have been published defining ways to add such missing information in a secured, signed, way, e.g. the ESS certificate identifiers ([RFC 2634](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2634) / [RFC 5035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5035)) for the secured identification of the signer certificate.

Collections of such extra attributes have been declared mandatory for signatures to have a certain legal value, e.g. as part of ISIS-MTT / Common PKI. Signature application in use in contexts where such a legal value is required, therefore, can count on those additional attributes to be present in a signature allowing for proper validation of the signatures.

While at first such collections were defined in smaller contexts only, e.g. on a national basis, meanwhile such collections are defined internationally, too.

CAdES specifies such collections (aka profiles) for all of Europe (and adopted also beyond).

In essence, creating CMS signatures according to such a profile makes sure that your signatures can be properly processed by very many applications and, therefore, their legal value immediately are recognized by them.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers @mkl. if I want to implement CAdES A Basic Electronic Signature (CAdES-BES) in Java , there is a big difference in the code with this one and CMS??

Comment: That depends on your CMS code... if it is flexible, CAdES-enabling it might be as easy as adding a very few lines. If it is not flexible, you might have to throw it away and start anew. I propose you start a new question posting the pivotal parts of your CMS generating code and ask for inspiration for making it generate CAdES-BES.